Add a link to an access file in sharepoint online
In my organization, we have an access file in which everyone can add new lines according to the work they do. And now, we adopted sharepoint online to manage our intranet.
The file is in a server folder like this:
\\server01\folder\access_file.mdb

We want to create a page, in sharepoint online, with a link to this file (to open it directly in the server, not to download it to user PC), but we are not able at all. No matter how we include the link in the page, sharepoint online always convert it to a link with "file:", like this:
file://server01/folder/access_file.mdb

No one can open the file this way, and in the chrome console we get the error:
Not allowed to load local resource: file://server01/folder/access_file.mdb

Can anyone help us?
Thanks in advance!
